# JS Reaching and Using Parent Object's Variable

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a quick question. Let me tell you about the process. I want to create shapes into canvas in js. My shapes are triangle,rectangle and square. Square object extended from rectangle and uses rectangle's constructor.

I can print rectangle easily but printing square is not easy as it is. Code will be helpful.

## RECTANGLE.js

```
function Rectangle(p, firstsideoflenght, secondsideoflenght) {
this.p1 = p
this.firstsideoflenght = firstsideoflenght
this.secondsideoflenght = secondsideoflenght
this.p2 = new Point(p.x + firstsideoflenght, p.y);
this.p3 = new Point(p.x, p.y + secondsideoflenght);
this.p4 = new Point(p.x + firstsideoflenght, p.y + secondsideoflenght);

this.getArea = function () {
    return firstsideoflenght * secondsideoflenght;
}
}
```

my points are p1 p2 p3 and p4. Im using that points to draw as you know.

## SQUARE.js

```
function Square(p, sidelength) {
Rectangle.call(p, sidelength, sidelength);
}
```

Square.js uses rectangles constructor.

I have a main.js to execute my codes.

## MAIN.js

```
/*var topLeft = new Point(200, 200);
var myRectangle = new Rectangle(topLeft, 50, 100);
myRectangle.points = [myRectangle.p1, myRectangle.p2, myRectangle.p4, myRectangle.p3];
myRectangle.init();
myRectangle.draw();*/

var topLeft = new Point(130, 130);
var mySquare = new Square(topLeft, 50);
debugger
mySquare.points = [mySquare.p1, mySquare.p2, mySquare.p3, mySquare.p4];
mySquare.init();
mySquare.draw();
```

At this point, i can't reach that points with using square. Console says mySquare.p1 undefined.

Thanks. I hope i could express myself well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass context as the first argument to `Function.prototype.call`

```
function Square(p, sidelength) {
  Rectangle.call(this, p, sidelength, sidelength);
```

```js
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

function Rectangle(p, firstsideoflenght, secondsideoflenght) {
this.p1 = p
this.firstsideoflenght = firstsideoflenght
this.secondsideoflenght = secondsideoflenght
this.p2 = new Point(p.x + firstsideoflenght, p.y);
this.p3 = new Point(p.x, p.y + secondsideoflenght);
this.p4 = new Point(p.x + firstsideoflenght, p.y + secondsideoflenght);

this.getArea = function () {
    return firstsideoflenght * secondsideoflenght;
}
}

function Square(p, sidelength) {
  Rectangle.call(this, p, sidelength, sidelength);
}

var topLeft = new Point(130, 130);
var mySquare = new Square(topLeft, 50);

console.log(mySquare.p1, mySquare.p2, mySquare.p3, mySquare.p4)
```